# Semi Implicit Euler method to solve system of ODEs in python

Tags: python, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

Hi Hoping some higher power at SO could help me with this problem. I have a system of 3 ODEs that I'm trying to solve using the semi-implicit Euler method. The equations are:

[image]

My knowledge of Numerical Analysis is best described as a novice, I have researched how best to solve a system of such equations and from what I can tell the semi-implicit euler method as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method) seems like the most sure way.

The code is as follows:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.constants import elementary_charge as ec
from scipy.constants import Planck as h

# Constants 
phi0 = h / (2*ec)
data_points = 10000
pp = 2*pi
f = (pp/phi0)
ff = phi0/pp
Ic = 340e-6
Rn = 1.1764705882352944 
Cj = (0.1*phi0)/ (pp*Ic*Rn**2)
Ib = 600e-6
Lp = 1e-12
#Initial conditions
v0 = 0
Is0 = 0
x0 = 0

#Time derivation
dt = 1e-13

#element arrays
Is = zeros(data_points)
x = zeros(data_points)
v = zeros(data_points)
time = zeros(data_points)

#Allocating initial values
v[0] = v0
Is[0] = Is0
x[0] = x0

#Loop of iteration steps 
for i in range(0, data_points-1):
    time[i+1] = time[i] + dt

    v[i+1] =  v[i]+(1/cj)*dt*((1/Cj)*((Ib-Ic*sin((x[i]*time[i]))-(Is[i]*time[i]) )))

    Is[i+1] = Is[i]+(1/Np)*dt*(((v[i+1]*time[i])-(Is[i]*time[i]*Rn)))

    x[i+1] = x[i]+f*dt*(v[i+1]*time[i+1])
```

Minus the long list of constants and initial conditions my main issue surrounds the Euler for loop and my implemntation for both `x` and `Is`. The reason I know the code does not produce sensible results come from the excpectation that the array `x` should have `max(x)` at around 1000-1500 at `max(time)` and has 2pi transition through the graph.

Comment: Are the values at i = 1 what you expect them to be?

Comment: @saulspatz Do you mean `Is[1]`? I'm not really sure since the only conditions I am provided are that `x[0],v[0],Is[0] = 0`. I just know the type of relationship the different variable should have. i.e. 2pi transitions should be observed in `x`, a sinusoidal relationship should be observed in `v` and `I`

Comment: You should check the computed values for the first couple of values of i, to be sure that you've programmed the formulas correctly.  Are the values python is computing for x[1], v[1], etc the values that you expect to see?

Comment: Unless you are trying to learn about numerical integrations by implementing it yourself, why not simply use `scipy.integrate.ode` ? It would be simpler, faster and more precise. It also use more rebust algorithms than the semi-implicit Euler method,  if your problem is non-linear or stiff.